# What is the Sefer Darchei Teshuvah about?

Tags: jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, yoreh-deah

I heard about a sefer (book) called *Darchei Teshuvah* by Rabbi Tsvi Hersh Shapiro.

What is the purpose of the Sefer? What is the story behind the author?

There’s not much about it on Google.

Comment: I spelled the last name wrong it seems: https://www.geni.com/people/R-Zvi-Hirsch-Spira-Admur-Munkacs/6000000007551474452

Comment: A compilation of various teshuvos on Yoreh Deah topics (super commentary ). It was done by his talmidim and he was General editor.

Comment: It's similar to the Mishnah berurah in that it's a digest of achronim on the Shulchan Aruch. Although from what I've seen he brings basically everything instead of the selective style of the MB.